# Fourier transform - next step

Tags: fourier-transform, heat-equation

> Given the initial boundary value problem for the heat equation:
>   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$$
>   $$u(0,t) = 0, t>0$$ 
>   $$u(x,0) = f(x), 0<x<\infty$$ 
>   Where $u=u(x,t)$ and $f(x)$ is a given smooth function.
>   Solve this problem by taking Fourier sine transforms and Fourier inverse sine transforms in the $x$ variable

So I've been able to use the Fourier sine transforms to transform the whole equation to get:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}F_s(u)+\alpha^2F_s(u)=0$$
and using the integrating factor $e^{\alpha^2t}$, I was able to show that 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}e^{\alpha^2t}F_s(u)=0$$
What's the next step in the methods? How do the initial boundary values apply here?

Comment: Now you have a very easy equation to solve to find $F_s[u](t,\xi)$ in terms of $F_s[u](0,\xi)$ (it is just an ODE for each fixed $\xi$). After that you need to do the inverse transform. The initial condition comes in because $F_s[u](0,\xi)=F_s[f](\xi)$.

Comment: @Ian so then $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}e^{\alpha^2x}F_s(f(x))=0$ where does the $t$ come into this?

Comment: You made a mistake in that it should be $e^{\alpha^2 t}$ not $e^{\alpha^2 x}$. It comes in there.